# The Printer is recognized and installed but it does not print actually

Tags: release-juno, drivers, printer

I connected an old HP 1018. The Printer is recognized, installed, but when I try to print, the documents stop in the printing pool. The system (5.0 Juno 64bit) flags them as printed while they're not. The files in the printing pool cannot be deleted either. The only way to stop this is to remove the printer.

Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check: http://localhost:631/admin/log/error_log | http://localhost:631/admin/log/page_log | /var/log/syslog (right after you try to print)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with 'Hannah' which can download and install the (right) HP 1018 driver, among several others.

From the Test Print it appears to be the "FOO2ZJS-.PPD", v1.1.

---

You can install `hannah-foo2zjs` running

```
sudo apt install hannah-foo2zjs
```

[image]

ref: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/hannah-foo2zjs

Comment: Please mark your answer as **answer**.

Answer (score 0):

What's up?

Try to install `system-config-printer` in your PC and configure your print by it

```
sudo apt install system-config-printer 

system-config-printer
```

It works with me. This software recognized my print perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my HP Officejet 5605z. This model is not featured by the above mentioned Hannah software. In another forum I read, that a user was able to solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling hplip. I did so. This did not initially solve my problem. However, in the installation log in the terminal it also says:

```
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
hplip-doc hplip-gui python3-notify2
```

(German for recommended packages). I installed these, in particular to try the gui.

Subsequently in the Elementary OS Apps searchbox it shows "HPLIP Toolbox". This I opened.

Here there is a guide showing on how to setup new devices, which I did. I was able to add my printer (was automatically recommended) and print a test page.

Now I tried to go to my desired documents and print one of them. In the print wizzard there are now two additional entries, the middle one successfully prints my documents now.

[image: print_wizzard]